# Fillable textboxes in PDF are not unique - all are duplicates of each other in the pdf, how to fix?

Tags: r, pdf, textbox, r-markdown

I am creating a report to send out to people and have them respond in the pdf with input in Adobe to save and send back to me.

I have managed to make text fields with hyperreff; however, the output pdf's textboxes duplicate eachother - so if I put "def" in one textbox - all the other textboxes in the document also put "def".

I am using:
`\begin{Form} \TextField[width = 10cm, height = 3cm, multiline=true]{ } \end{Form}`

which is used later in the document for user input:

`\begin{Form} \TextField[width = 10cm, height = 3cm, multiline=true]{ } \end{Form}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a unique name to each field otherwise they all get the same name and then, in Acrobat, the same value when you edit one of them. See the name property below.

\begin{Form} \TextField[name = foo, width = 10cm, height = 3cm, multiline=true]{ } \end{Form}